# Add support for multiple languages to Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

First of all, I know that SE primary language is english, and I'm fine with that. But I was thinking that adding support for multiple languages to the Developer Story would be a nice feature to have.

To clarify, I'm not asking to have another language to the UX of the developer story, just to choose a language to **display the information in it**.

If this is added, all the information in the languages that the user chooses, would be filled by the user itself.

So, for instance,

> https://stackoverflow.com/story/some_user/en

would show every item in english (if it was filled by the user) and

> https://stackoverflow.com/story/some_user/es

could show it in spanish.

Comment: I made an edit to make it more clear what you mean - if you don't like it, feel free to roll bakc

Answer (score 5):

This *would* make sense - and with a huge set of languages, not just the ones Stack Overflow happens to support.

The Developer Story is supposed to work independently from Stack Overflow Jobs, which is limited to select few languages. It is supposed to be a tool to show off your achievements, and to be something to show to potential employers.

Because a huge number of developers on Stack Overflow lives in markets where English is not a primary (or even second) language, it can do this effectively only through supporting the local language.